# Connect Grails Gorm to preexisting MySQL DB

Tags: mysql, grails, groovy, grails-orm

I am trying to connect to an existing table and use it in my application.
However, when I try to access my information within my controller it comes back null.

The code:

**build.gradle** (relevant parts)

```
dependencies {
    classpath "org.grails:grails-gradle-plugin:$grailsVersion"
    classpath "org.grails.plugins:hibernate5:${gormVersion-".RELEASE"}"
    classpath "org.grails.plugins:views-gradle:1.1.6"
}

apply plugin:"org.grails.grails-web"
apply plugin:"org.grails.plugins.views-json"

dependencies {
    compile "org.grails.plugins:hibernate5:6.1.9"
    compile "org.hibernate:hibernate-ehcache"
    runtime 'mysql:mysql-connector-java:5.1.40' 
}
```

**application.yml** (relevant parts)

```
hibernate:
    cache:
        queries: false
        use_second_level_cache: false
        use_query_cache: false
        region.factory_class: org.hibernate.cache.ehcache.SingletonEhCacheRegionFactory

dataSource:
    pooled: true
    jmxExport: true
    driverClassName: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
    dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect
    username: abc
    password: ''

environments:
    development:
        dataSource:
            dbCreate: create-drop
            url: jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/moocs?useSSL=false
    test:
        dataSource:
            dbCreate: update
            url: jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/moocs?useSSL=false
    production:
        dataSource:
            dbCreate: none
            url: jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/moocs?useSSL=false
            properties:
                jmxEnabled: true
                initialSize: 5
                maxActive: 50
                minIdle: 5
                maxIdle: 25
                maxWait: 10000
                maxAge: 600000
                timeBetweenEvictionRunsMillis: 5000
                minEvictableIdleTimeMillis: 60000
                validationQuery: SELECT 1
                validationQueryTimeout: 3
                validationInterval: 15000
                testOnBorrow: true
                testWhileIdle: true
                testOnReturn: false
                jdbcInterceptors: ConnectionState
                defaultTransactionIsolation: 2 # TRANSACTION_READ_COMMITTED
```

**Model**

```
class MoocModel {
    String title
    String institution
    String url
    Boolean free
    String platform
}
```

**DB Table**

```
+--------------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field              | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+--------------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| primary_key_column | bigint(20)   | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| free               | bit(1)       | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| title              | varchar(255) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| url                | varchar(255) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| platform           | varchar(255) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| institution        | varchar(255) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
+--------------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

**Controller**

```
import MoocModel

import grails.rest.*
import grails.converters.*

class TableController {
    static responseFormats = ['json', 'xml']

    def index() { 
        def mm = MoocModel
        render mm.get(5) as JSON  // want to display entry with id == 5 
    }
}
```

I am getting an empty array back, `println mm.get(5)` returns `null` so I think there is no connection being made with the DB.

Answer (score 0):

You need to map your fields to DB columns. By default grails uses 'id' column as primary key.
So try to add to MoocModel:

```
static mapping = {
    id name: 'primary_key_column'
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that

```
dataSource:
            dbCreate: create-drop
            url: jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/moocs?useSSL=false
```

Would delete the existing table, so I changed the `dbCreate` to `update`

Answer (score 0):

By default, GRAILS  create a field in the database

```
version
```

To control the version of each entity, and as Evengy said you have to map the default ID of your class

```
static mapping = {
    id name: 'primary_key_column'
}
```

And if is an existing database you can't use create-drop because he will try to create all the columns, so change the create-drop to update

```
dataSource:
            dbCreate: create-drop
            url: jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/moocs?useSSL=false
dataSource:
            dbCreate: update
            url: jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/moocs?useSSL=false
```